# Which W to report for the Wilcoxon test?

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

Imagine that I have the following data:

```
GroupA <- c(2,4,3,1,2,3,3,2,3,1)
GroupB <- c(3,5,4,2,4,3,5,5,3,2)
```

Then when I call in R

```
wilcox.test(GroupA, GroupB)
```

and then

```
wilcox.test(GroupB, GroupA)
```

I get different $W$'s (but the same p-value).

**Questions:**
Why is this happening? (Am I doing something wrong here?)

What is the correct interpretation for this?

Which $W$ should I choose when reporting the results?

Comment: Have you read about how W is computed?  If you're going to use it, you might as well know! E.g., see http://www.sussex.ac.uk/Users/grahamh/RM1web/WilcoxonHandoout2011.pdf.  That should *immediately* answer all your questions.

Comment: @whuber Thank you! I also found this [table](http://math.usask.ca/~laverty/S245/Tables/wmw.pdf) useful. Two questions: is W the same as U in case of a Wilcoxon rank sum test (equivalent to Mann-Whitney's U)? And when W=0 is this the real W, even when the "other W" is >0?

Comment: The "note" section in the [R manual page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html) might address your followup question (which I don't understand; I'm guessing what you're trying to get at).

Comment: @whuber The "note" seems to be talking about the lack of unanimity on how to calculate the test statistic. But my question is this: R has function `wilcox.test` to compute Mann-Whitney U test, but this function returns "W=...", so is this W (the lowest) the value of U?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have ten elements of each group, so you are doing $10 \times 10 =100$ comparisons.

Your first test tells you that in $23$ comparisons Group A elements are bigger than Group B elements (with equalities counting as $0.5$). Your second test tells you that in $77$ comparisons Group B elements are bigger than Group A elements.

Fortunately $23+77=100$ so there is no problem and you can report whichever you prefer.

Comment: ?! Should I report whichever I prefer, or always the lowest W (even if 0), as this is the value that is compared to the critical one in the Wilcoxon Rank Sum Table?

Comment: You just want to be clear: so for example if you report a central value for Group A before you report a central value for Group B then it is natural to report the $U$ for the first test statistic.

Comment: I have boxplots showing the median, the mean, etc, then I have a Wilcoxon rank sum test, say returning W=0 (the lowest), p=0.0034, so from what I understood I can report this as "The Mann-Whitney U test confirms a statistical significance effect (U=0, p<0.05)". Is this correct ?

Comment: You should report the numbers in each group too.  $U=23$ means something very different when $n_A=n_B=5$ compared with $n_A=n_B=10$.

Comment: Yes, I did not forget to mention the sample sizes in each group in my boxplots. So, W and U are the same thing for Wilcoxon rank sum/Mann-Whitney U, and the lowest value of the groups is chosen. Thank you!